# Delete all code inside a tag in multiple HTML files with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, html, find-and-replace

I need to delete all code contained within

`<li class="share"> ... </li>`

including the `<li>` tags themselves.

There are multiple other `<li>` tags inside the `li class="share"` tag, so I'm not quite sure how to approach this.  I am using Notepad++.

Comment: That's not an easy question. You could write a parser for that - but depending on content of your files it might be not-so-trivial. For example, if these are php files you might have to take into account that there may be things like `<li class="<?php echo $cell["additional_class"]; ?> share fubar"> ... </li>`.
You can't just write a regex for that... Or at least it wouldn't be an easy one if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, below is a quickly thrown together code that seems to work alright for *simple* data example. Do what you will with it.

Yes, this is not something you can do with a simple Find&Replace in Notepad, even Regex available in F&R in N++ doesn't really give you the ability to do that... Or of it is possible in Regex - It's well beyond my level. ;)

```python
import sys
import re

def get_tag():
    buffer = ""
    while True:
        c = sys.stdin.read(1)
        if not c:
            sys.stderr.write("Unexpected EOF\n")
            break
        buffer += c
        if c == '"' or c == "'":
            buffer += get_string(c)
        if c == '>':
            break
    return buffer

def get_string(quote = '"'):
    buffer = ""
    while True:
        c = sys.stdin.read(1)
        if not c:
            sys.stderr.write("Unexpected EOF\n")
            break
        buffer += c
        if c == quote and buffer[-2] != '\\':
            break
    return buffer


buffer = ""
skip_depth = 0

ul_begin = re.compile(r"<\s*li(?:>|\s+.*>)", re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
ul_begin_share = re.compile(r"<\s*li\s+.*class\s*=\s*([\"'])(?:[^\1]*?\s+)?share(?:\s+[^\1]*?)?(\1).*?>", re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
ul_end = re.compile(r"</\s*li\s*>", re.IGNORECASE)


while True:
    if skip_depth < 0:
        skip_depth = 0
    c = sys.stdin.read(1)
    if not c:
        #sys.stderr.write("EOF\n")
        break

    if c == '<':
        buffer = c + get_tag()

        if skip_depth > 0 and ul_begin.match(buffer):
            skip_depth += 1
        elif ul_begin_share.match(buffer):
            skip_depth += 1
        elif ul_end.match(buffer):
            skip_depth -= 1
            if skip_depth == 0:
                continue
        c = buffer

    if skip_depth > 0:
        pass
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
```

Test data in data.html:

```
<ul>
    <li>do not touch that</li>
    <li id="whatever1">or that</li>
    <li class="share">delete this</li>
    <li class="foo-bar share">delete this</li>
    <li class="foobar share foo-bar_">delete this</li>
    <li class='share'>delete this</li>
    <li class='"wtf" share'>delete this</li>
    <li class=" share ">delete this</li>
    <li class="  share  ">delete this</li>
    <li class="foo share">delete this</li>
    <li class="share bar">delete this</li>
    <li class="foo share bar">delete this</li>
    <li class="long foo share short bar">delete this</li>
    <li class=" share ">delete this</li>
    <li class=" foo share bar ">delete this</li>
    <!-- but leave <li class="share">this comment</li> alone -->
    <li>This will stay</li>
    <li class="share">
        <li>delete this</li>
        <li>delete this</li>
    </li>
    <li style="not !important" class="share">delete this</li>
    <li>leave this, but
        <li class="share">
            <li>delete this</li>
            <li>delete this</li>
            <li>delete this</li>
            <li>delete this</li>
        </li>
    </li>
    <li class=" foo share bar ">delete this</li>
    <li class="shared">Can't touch this, naaaa-nanana...</li>
</ul>
<em>blablabla</em>
```

Example run:

```
$ python test.py < data.html > data.corrected.html
$ cat data.corrected.html
<ul>
    <li>do not touch that</li>
    <li id="whatever1">or that</li>













    <!-- but leave <li class="share">this comment</li> alone -->
    <li>This will stay</li>


    <li>leave this, but

    </li>

    <li class="shared">Can't touch this, naaaa-nanana...</li>
</ul>
<em>blablabla</em>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering the question!  But what do I do with this code?  Do I need a python environment to run these parsers?  I think it might be easier to take care of `<li>` tags inside `<li class="share"> ... </li>` first and then run a "Find and replace in files".

Comment: @RandyS  Yes, to run it you need [python 3](https://www.python.org/downloads/) installed, then you can run it just like I wrote: `python test.py < data.html > data.corrected.html`, so just like any other console utility, where `test.py` is the Python script I wrote, `data.html` is the original file that is read from, and `data.corrected.html` is where you save the corrected version. I suppose I could try to make it work with N++ Python script plugin, but I've never worked with that, so I don't know if I could just modify the file in-place like that via that plugin.

Comment: @RandyS it seems it would be trivial to change the script to work inside N++ thanks to Python Scripting plugin, however... What *should* work - doesn't in my case. Even empty script crashes N++ for me, and thus I'm in the process of asking what is going on on the plugin forums. Hopefully the author of it will help me get my installation going, and then I'll post the results here.
If only everything would be as smooth as we wanted, eh? ;)

Comment: I ended up going the simpler route and deleted the inside tags first, then did a find and replace for all the empty tags.  Thank you for your help! :)